# How to dynamically change UITableView section header with scrolling. Or how to add a button to table section header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

The default behavior for UITableView section headers is to stick to the top edge of the table and slightly change background to a thin material.

[image]
[image]

I need to add a button to the section header, so, as I understand, I need to write my own custom header with the `viewForHeaderInSection`. How do I replicate the default behavior of changing the background to a thin material? How do I detect that the section header hit the top edge of the table and force to change the view's background?

Alternatively, how can I add a button to the standard header without writing my own?

Comment: check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670152/detect-when-uitableview-section-header-snaps-to-the-top-of-the-screen

Comment: If you subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView and add your button there, it changes the background to a thin material for you automatically. As far as replicating the behavior maybe you can look at the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method

Comment: @willThatBeAll UITableViewHeaderFooterView is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a simple subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` helped. It kept all the standard behavior and visuals, while I just added a button on top.